# A book or tutorial/guide for "Systems Interfaces & Deployment"

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a complete guide (call it a book, tutorial, guide or whatever) about some programming topics which are not enough covered by Mathematica Documentation Center, in my opinion. Topics like 
 - WSTP API
 - Wolfram LibraryLink
 - .NET Interface
 - Java Interface
are not well documented. Basically there is just a list all functions and related reference pages, whereas I would read something more comprehensive speaking about the rationale and the surrounding aspects of linking Mathematica with other technologies. 
Of course I mean also commercial books not just free resources.

Comment: For the now outdated `MathLink` there is [MathLink: Network Programming with Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=1326) and [MathLink Development in C](https://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/MathLinkDevelopmentInC/). The [Systems Interfaces and Deployment](https://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/SystemsInterfacesAndDeployment/) is from 2008 using *Mathematica* 7.0.

Comment: @Karsten, thanks for the answer. I have the two WRI tutorials, but I think with recent versions many things have been changed and many others have been added, so I'm looking for an updated material.

Comment: I also would appreciate up-to-date, comprehensive guides on these topics. The book I linked to is based on *Mathematica* 4. [New in 8.0: Systems Interfaces & Deployment](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NewIn80SystemsInterfacesAndDeployment.html) and [New in 9.0: Systems Interfaces & Deployment](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NewIn90SystemsInterfacesAndDeployment.html) provide and overview of the update in version 8 and 9.

Comment: Since version 10 updates in these area seem to be classified under different names (e.g. `LinkActivate` can be found in the "Cloud Operation & Deployment" category in [Summary of New Features in 10.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn102.html)). Presumably [WSTP and External Program Communication](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPAndExternalProgramCommunicationOverview.html) is currently the best starting point for WSTP.

Comment: [Systems Interfaces & Deployment](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SystemsInterfacesAndDeploymentOverview.html) seems to be the best entry point to these user guides.

Comment: @Karsten, these links are a good starting point, it seems I missed a couple of them when looking around inside the documentation center. Thanks a lot for the support.